# How to read and write on secure element on mobile device for NFC payment purposes?

Tags: android, nfc, payment, secure-element

I'm  working on e-payment mobile application and he need some answers for the following questions:

1. How much cards details can be saved on the secured element on the mobile device? and is it encrypted?
2. I have multiple payment cards in my application and if we assumed they all saved on the secured elements (encrypted). how I can get one card details to use it in NFC payment?
3. on tab and pay, the NFC called the card details from the secured element and pass them through NFC to the point of sale? is that true?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, contactless payments are standardized by an organization called EMVCo, so it is never a bad idea to spend some time reading the documentation. You can start here: https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx

Some quick answers to your questions:

1. Card details are the ones you can see printed on a card, plus secret keys and credentials. They are as good as encrypted: the Secure Element will not yield data without a mutual authentication procedure, and those data will be encrypted.
2. You need the permission/collaboration of the card's issuing organization (typically a bank or financial institution). Remember, card details are very well protected
3. Yes, if by "the NFC" you mean the contactless reader at the point of sale, which will initiate the transaction.